# Calling different API with different interval time , saved in my database table

Tags: c#, .net, api, system.timers.timer

I have a list of API from different client saved in my Database table and all the API have different time interval for there API to be called. What should be my approach to call the API. New data may be added in the List of API table . Should I go for Dynamic Timers?

1. I have an application (GUI) which clients use to add new records.
2. These records represent an API url and the time (Schedule) at which that API should be called.
3. Your Challenge is to write code that is able to call all the Client specified API's at the specified schedule/time.

Comment: How accurate do you need the timing to be? How often are timers added?

Comment: "Accurate" isn't a binary "yes or no" though. Do you need to make the call to the right millisecond? The right second? The right minute? The right 10 minutes?

Comment: The timing will be configured based on different API from the front end , it can millisecond or minute depending upon the client .

Comment: I'm not asking about how often it's called. I'm asking how important the accuracy is. If you schedule something to happen at 9 o'clock exactly, how close to 9 o'clock to you need it to happen? If it happens at 9:01, is that okay? What about 9:00:01?

Comment: Yes it will be okay.

Comment: Which will be okay? And how much variation *is* okay? Would it be okay at 9:10? Please edit your question to make the requirements a lot clearer.

Comment: A variation of about less than 5 minutes will be fine not more.

Comment: Right. That's all I was asking for in the original comment. Please update your question to make that information clear so other users don't need to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

To me - API calling & Handling the responses (Storing into DB etc) should be one component. and, scheduling when to call which API - should be other component (Something like cron job). This way - when the time is right appropriate API call would be triggered. This also gives you flexibility to do multiple tries/retries in a day etc.

**Update after your comment:**

1. You have an application (GUI) which clients use to add new records.
2. These records represent an API url and the time (Schedule) at which that API should be called.
3. Your Challenge is to write code that is able to call all the Client specified API's at the specified schedule/time.

If I have got that problem right - my original suggestion stands.

**Component 1 - Scheduler**
Use Quartz.net (or create your own using a Timer etc) - and create a Service (say WCF) or Process which will read records from Database and identify all the schedules and the API urls that need to be called. When the scheduled time happens Quartz.net will trigger your handler method - where you will make a Call to Component 2 and pass on the API url.

**Component 2 - API Engine**
When it receives a call from Component 1 - it will make the API call and fetch the response. Store/process it as required.

Comment: (Storing into DB etc) is handled in the application where different client can configure there API and interval time .  Later in API I need to call these client API with different time interval for request and response.

Comment: @Alicia - Updated my response

Answer (score 0):

There are various schedulers that can be used to do this automatically. For example, you could use [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net) and its `AdoJobStore`. I haven't used that myself, but it [sounds appropriate](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html):

> With the use of the included AdoJobStore, all Jobs and Triggers configured as "non-volatile" are stored in a relational database via ADO.NET.

Alternatively, your database may well have timers built into it. However, if this is primarily an academic exercise (as suggested by "your challenge") you may not be able to use these.

I would keep a table of scheduled tasks, with columns specifying:

- When the task should next be run
- What the task should do
- How to work out the next iteration of that task afterwards
- If the task has been started, when it was started
- If the task completed, when it completed

You can then write code in an infinite loop to just scan that table, e.g. once per minute. It should look for all tasks with a "next time" earlier than now that haven't completed:

- If the task hasn't been started, update the row to show that it *has* been started (now), and start executing the task
- If the task was started recently, ignore it
- If the task was started "a long time ago" (i.e. longer than it would take to run successfully), either mark it as "broken" somehow, or restart

When a task completes successfully, update the row to indicate that it's finished, and add another row for the next time it should be started.

You'll need to work out exactly what your error strategy is:

- How long should the gap be between a task starting and you deciding it's failed?
- Do you always want to restart the task, or should some failures be permanent?
- Do you need to record how often a task failed, and give up after a certain number of tries?
- What do you do if you explicitly notice that the task has failed while you're executing it? (Rather than just by the fact that it was started a long time ago.)

For extra reliability, you'd need to think of other aspects too:

- Do you need multiple task runners?
- How can you spot when a task runner has failed, and restart that?
- How do you deal with multiple task runners trying to start the same task at the same time?

You may not need to actually implement everything here, but it's worth considering them.